# WPF-DirectX Interop Problem (D3DImage)

Tags: wpf, interop, directx, direct3d

I'm writing a Video application utilizing D3DImage. Frames are from memory and rendered as textures in native code with DirectX9, finally exposed by D3DImage to the WPF GUI. I have some Overlays on top, created with WPF's painting framework (Text, shapes etc.). Up to this point, it works like a charm.
Now, I would like encode the composited image from my underlying native C++ code. Video is 640x480 BGR, 25 FPS and has to be rendered and encoded in parallel, also on older Hardware with Windows versions down to XP/SP3.

Problem is, I cannot find any documentation describing the composition process between WPF and D3DImage. They 'blend' in some sense, but what is the meaning of this? And is it possible to get a handle to the WPF's part of the drawing or even the composited image in my native C++ code?

p.s: I'm also open to managed solutions, but didn't found much performant up to now.

Answer (score 2):

There is global static method called "CompositionTarget.Rendering". Add an event to that and every time WPF renders that method will be called before WPF presents(the FPS can vary though). So just updated your renderTarget accordingly.
There might be a better way, but i'm not aware of it.

NOTE:: Also for D3DImage on WindowsXP you use a D3D9 device with a lockable renderTarget while on Vista/7 you use a D3D9Ex device with a non-lockable renderTarget. Just a note.